# Silver Polished material in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new to three js and trying to create a cube like this:
[image: 3D Cube]
I can't figure out how to create the material for my cube. The material seems to be silver polished. It has reflection and nice edges. Would you please help me to find out which material with which parameters will give me result like that?

Comment: SO is not intended to do your coding for you. Show your current code so we can help instead of create.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen i know so isn't about coding for others. I think I don't ask the question well or putting the picture made you misunderstood. I'm not asking how i code all the cube i just ask which material , with which params would gave me a silver like material. as you can see answer of @ WestLangley the answer don't need my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshPhongMaterial) and set the `envMap` property to the `renderTarget` of the camera you want to use for reflection.
For the polished look you can use a texture in the `specularMap` property (or even the `specular` property).

The smooth edges are done by calling [`geometry.computeVertexNormals()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Geometry.computeVertexNormals).

**Edit**: As mentioned by @prisoner849, `computeVertexNormals` needs to be called *before* you apply the material.

**Edit 2**: As requested by @prisoner849, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/juanferrer/pen/xrmxgj)

**Edit 3**: @WestLangley mentioned using `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()` should work better, so the example has been updated to reflect that.

Comment: Did I get it right, that if I use, for example, `var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(2, 2, 2);` and then `geometry.computeVertexNormals()` and after all I'll use this geometry with `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()` in a mesh, then I'll get a cube with smooth rounded edges?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, could you tweak [this](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/2j773mw1/) so the edges of geometries will become rounded.

Comment: `computeVertexNormals()` only makes the renderer take into account the normals of the faces and average the edges. Thus, you get a smooth look. But the mesh is still a box with sharp edges. If you want to have *real* smooth edges, you need a mesh that has them. You can easily do it with a 3D editor.

Comment: Actually, it can be done to the mesh, but it's a bit more complex (and quite more computationally expensive for that amount of models). [Here's the example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_modifier_subdivision). It's done using [`THREE.SubdivisionModifier()`](https://threejs.org/examples/js/modifiers/SubdivisionModifier.js).

Comment: @prisoner849 Just added a working example. I used most of your work, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Great job. I perfectly don't mind that you used my work ) But I'm still wondering, why in your answer you didn't mention that it needs a totally different geometry, if you want to have rounded edges.

Comment: @JuanFerrer thanks for your answer. It looks good like polished metal. Although it is too dark and isn't like silver. thanks anyway.

Comment: @prisoner849 thanks dude to being enthusiastic about the issue.

Comment: is it correct that, if you use `THREE.SubdivisionModifier()`, you can't control edges' roundness (radius)?

Answer (score 9):

You want to create a silver, polished material in three.js.

`MeshStandardMaterial` is a physically-based material and was designed for that purpose.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {
    metalness: 1,   // between 0 and 1
    roughness: 0.5, // between 0 and 1
    envMap: envMap,
} );
```

Be sure to specify an environment map so there is something to reflect. Adjust the other parameters to your liking.

three.js r.86

Comment: It is also the correct answer. `MeshPhongMaterial` does not model metals correctly. Nor is it physically based. And `MeshPhongMaterial` does not properly handle reflections when a material's roughness is changed.

Comment: would you please change material of [this codepen](https://codepen.io/juanferrer/pen/xrmxgj) too look like silver polished.

Comment: Use the material parameters I posted above. You can adjust the roughness if you want. Also, you have too much light in the scene. Reduce the intensity of your directional light. You can also increase or decrease `material.envMapIntensity.`  You can change the material color from white to silver if you want.